# rmmod for my platform driver causes kernel panic?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, gpio

I have written a simple GPIO *sysfs* driver. However, my driver is crashing when I call `rmmod`. I don't know what I am missing. I am suspecting that my `probe()` function is causing this issue. I am using kernel 4.19 version. Here is my long code:

```c
struct of_device_id gpio_sysfs_dt_match[] = {
 { .compatible = "org,bone-gpio-sysfs" },
 { } // NULL terminated
};

ssize_t direction_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
   return 0;
}

ssize_t direction_store(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count)
{
  return 0;
}

ssize_t value_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
   return 0;
}

ssize_t value_store(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count)
{
  return 0;
}

ssize_t label_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
   return 0;
}

static DEVICE_ATTR_RW(direction);
static DEVICE_ATTR_RW(value);
static DEVICE_ATTR_RO(label);

static struct attribute *gpio_attrs[] = {
   &dev_attr_direction.attr,
   &dev_attr_value.attr,
   &dev_attr_label.attr,
   NULL
};

static struct attribute_group gpio_group = {
   .attrs = gpio_attrs,
};

const struct attribute_group *gpio_attr_groups[] =
{
   &gpio_group,
   NULL
};

int gpio_sysfs_platform_driver_probe (struct platform_device *pDev)
{   
   struct device_node *parent = pDev->dev.of_node;
   struct device_node *child;
   struct gpiodev_private_data *dev_data;
   struct device dev = pDev->dev;
   const char *name;
   int i = 0;
   int ret;
   
   gpiodrv_data.total_devices = of_get_child_count(parent);
   if (!gpiodrv_data.total_devices) {
      dev_err(&dev, "Error - No devices found\r\n");
      return -EINVAL;
   }
   dev_info(&dev, "child count = %d\r\n", gpiodrv_data.total_devices);
   gpiodrv_data.dev_sysfs = devm_kzalloc(&pDev->dev, sizeof(struct device *) * gpiodrv_data.total_devices, GFP_KERNEL);

   for_each_available_child_of_node(parent, child) {
      dev_data = devm_kzalloc(&dev, sizeof(struct gpiodev_private_data),GFP_KERNEL);
      if (!dev_data) {
         pr_err("No memory \r\n");
         return -ENOMEM;
      }
      if (of_property_read_string(child, "label", &name)) {
         pr_err("Missing label \r\n");
         snprintf(dev_data->label,sizeof(dev_data->label), "unknown-gpio-%d",i);
      } else {
         strcpy(dev_data->label, name);
         dev_info(&dev,"GPIO label = %s\n",dev_data->label);
      }
      dev_data->desc = devm_fwnode_get_gpiod_from_child(&dev,"bone",&child->fwnode, GPIOD_ASIS, dev_data->label);
      if (IS_ERR(dev_data->desc)) {
         ret = PTR_ERR(dev_data->desc);
         if(ret == -ENONET) {
            dev_err(&dev, "get gpiod failed - no entry found\r\n");
         }
         return ret;
      }
      /** gpio/gpio.txt **/
      ret = gpiod_direction_output(dev_data->desc, 0);
      if(ret) {
         dev_err(&dev,"Err setting gpio direction failed = %d\r\n",i);
         return ret;
      }
      
      gpiodrv_data.dev_sysfs[i] = device_create_with_groups(gpiodrv_data.class_gpio, &dev, 0, dev_data, gpio_attr_groups, dev_data->label);
      if(IS_ERR(gpiodrv_data.dev_sysfs[i])) {
         ret = PTR_ERR(gpiodrv_data.dev_sysfs[i]);
         dev_err(&dev, "Error creating device with groups \r\n");
         return ret;
      }
      i++;
   }

   return 0;
}

int gpio_sysfs_driver_remove(struct platform_device *pDev)
{ 
   int i = 0;
   dev_info(&pDev->dev, "Removing gpio syfs driver\r\n");
   
   for (i = 0; i < gpiodrv_data.total_devices; i++) {
      device_unregister(gpiodrv_data.dev_sysfs[i]);   
   }
   return 0;
}

struct platform_driver gpiosysfs_platform_driver = {
    .probe =  gpio_sysfs_platform_driver_probe,
    .remove = gpio_sysfs_driver_remove,
    .driver = {
          .name =  "bone-gpio-sysfs",
          . of_match_table = of_match_ptr(gpio_sysfs_dt_match),
    },  
};

/**Entry Point of the Kernel Module **/
/** Called when the module is inserted -insmod **/
static int __init gpio_sysfs_init(void)
{
   int ret;
   gpiodrv_data.class_gpio = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "bone_gpios");
   ret = platform_driver_register(&gpiosysfs_platform_driver);  
   return ret;  
}

/** Called when the module is removed - rmmod**/
static void __exit gpio_sysfs_exit(void)
{
   platform_driver_unregister(&gpiosysfs_platform_driver);
   class_destroy(gpiodrv_data.class_gpio);
   pr_info("module unloaded\n");
}
```

The problem is seen when I call `rmmod` of my driver. When I do this, I see a kernel crash - pointing to the platform driver **unregister**. What am I doing wrong here? If I comment out probe then I don't see this problem. Perhaps, some problem is introduced inside probe. As you can see I am using managed resource API so I guess, I don't have to call `kfree()` since I am using `dev_kzalloc()`.

Comment: Have you checked whether `class_gpio` a null pointer or  `platform_driver_register` failed?

Comment: Not sure if related, but I can't find the definition of `gpiodrv_data`. Also post your kernel panic message might help

Comment: The use of local variable `struct device dev = pDev->dev;` and subsequent use of `&dev` looks very wrong since the `dev` variable ceases to exist when the probe function returns.

Comment: Is there any reason that you cannot just replace `&dev` with `&pDev->dev`?

Comment: You care correct - The use of local variable struct device dev = pDev->dev; and subsequent use of &dev looks very wrong since the dev variable ceases to exist when the probe function returns.. This was the problem and it worked.